# JCarousel Lite and adding more images to a dynamically built list

Tags: jcarousellite

I've integrated jcarousel lite into a magento site for a product image gallery.

The page dynamically builds a list (via magento) of the necessary images.

However, as soon as jcarousel lite is added to the page, additional < li > can be seen in the < ul > part of the page.

In summary:
without jcarousel lite - correct number of images in the 
with jcarousel lite - additional items in the

here's how jcarousel lite is being invoked on the page in question:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery(".more-views").jCarouselLite({
        btnNext: ".next",
        visible: 1,
        speed: 500,
        btnPrev: ".prev"
    });
});
</script>
```

any hints on why this is occuring?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that's the way jCarouselLite works (and to that end, almost all 'carousel' or 'slider' types of plugins) -- ie, they duplicate the items that are 'out of view' so that you get a smooth transition as the user cycles through the items. This is normal functionality.